# Mapping error in Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm still a newbie in the Docker area. I'm just getting confused about this from this Docker-run command:

```bash
docker run -d --name fritzbox_smarthome_exporter -p 9103:9103 \
  -v $(pwd)/boxcert.cer:/fritzbox.pem:ro \
  -e PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin \
  -e PASSWORD=ChefsPassWord \
  -e USERNAME=chef \
  jaymedh/fritzbox_smarthome_exporter '-noverify=false' '-url=http://fritz.box' '-cert=/fritzbox.pem'
```

to create a corresponding `docker-compose.yml` file.

Can someone enlighten a blind person? Thanks.

This is my design:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  fritzbox_smarthome_exporter:
    image: 'jaymedh/fritzbox_smarthome_exporter:latest'
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - '9103:9103'
environment:
      USERNAME=Chef
      PASSWORD=cHefsPw
      PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
volumes: 
      - $(pwd)/boxcert.cer:/fritzbox.pem:ro
command: noverify=false url=http://192.168.0.2 cert=/fritzbox.pem
```

But Portainer throws the following error message:

```
failed to deploy a stack: validating /data/compose/25/docker-compose.yml: services.fritzbox_smarthome_exporter1.environment must be a mapping
```

Even if I replace the variable with the regular path on the system ( `- /opt/fritz_smarthome_exporter/boxcert.cer:/fritzbox.pem:ro` ), I get an error.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  fritzbox_smarthome_exporter:
    image: 'jaymedh/fritzbox_smarthome_exporter:latest'
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - '9103:9103'
environment:
      USERNAME=Chef
      PASSWORD=cHefsPw
      PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
volumes: 
      - /opt/fritbox_smarthome_exporter/boxcert.cer /fritzbox.pem:ro
command: noverify=false url=http://192.168.0.2 cert=/fritzbox.pem

the Error: failed to deploy a stack: validating /data/compose/38/docker-compose.yml: volumes must be a mapping
```

can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Indentation looks incorrect...Docker Composerize can help you: https://www.composerize.com

```
version: '3.3'
services:
    fritzbox_smarthome_exporter:
        container_name: fritzbox_smarthome_exporter
        ports:
            - '9103:9103'
        volumes:
            - ${PWD}/boxcert.cer:/fritzbox.pem:ro
        environment:
            PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
            PASSWORD: ChefsPassWord
            USERNAME: chef
        labels:
            - 'http://fritz.box'
        image: jaymedh/fritzbox_smarthome_exporter
        restart: unless-stopped
```

Comment: why does this list "true" twice as environment variables?

Comment: @Jesusaur good catch; I updated the docker-compose.yml...I had copied it from output at www.coposerize.com based on OP question's syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The format of your environment variables is incorrect. Additionally, using bash expansion for the volume path won't work, but you can use a relative path:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  fritzbox_smarthome_exporter:
    image: 'jaymedh/fritzbox_smarthome_exporter:latest'
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - '9103:9103'
    environment:
      USERNAME: Chef
      PASSWORD: cHefsPw
      PATH: "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
    volumes: 
      - ./boxcert.cer:/fritzbox.pem:ro
    command: "noverify=false url=http://192.168.0.2 cert=/fritzbox.pem"
```

You can read more about the docker compose file syntax [in the official docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#environment)

Comment: Hello,
unfortunately that still doesn't work. I get the following error:
failed to deploy a stack: validating /data/compose/40/docker-compose.yml: services.fritzbox_smarthome_exporter must be a mapping

Comment: @VaraBiker whoops, sorry, my indentation was incorrect, but I've fixed it.